# How to open . srt files in Ubuntu

Tags: subtitle

My problem is that I can't open .srt files. This file is in an .rar archive along with a .txt file. When I extract, only  the .txt file gets extracted. I downloaded several programs that are supposed to support this file format like Gnome Subtitles, but none of them works properly.

I keep getting the following error, even when I specify *Open with*:

[image]

Comment: .srt file are subtitle text files, that can easily be opened and edited with almost any standard text-editor application. Geany and gEdit are my favorites, for example, which do the job just fine. Also .srt file among others, are loaded as subtitles with the movie. Just make sure, that they are located in the same folder and have the same name!! Use VLC media player for instance or Totem (Movie Player) to play the movie and see the subtitles. Movie players load external subtitles automatically and/or have a menu option to load them manually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `.srt` file contains simple text in it. If you want to open a `.srt` file, open it with your favourite text editor to see the contents.

If you want to use the `.srt` file as subtitle with a video. First copy it to the same location that of the video. Rename it to the name of the video and open it with a media player e.g. vlc etc.

If your video name is `movie.mp4`, your subtitle name should be `movie.srt`.

**Note:** If you still have any problem. Go to **Video** >> **Subtitle Track** and check the `.srt` file is showing or not.

Comment: The problem is that i can't extract the .srt file therefore i can't access it due to the fact that it is in a .rar. I used subleme text 3 and it can't open the file as well.File names are exactly the same

Comment: You need to install `rar`. Use in terminal `sudo apt-get install rar unrar`. After that right click on the archive and extract.

Comment: It worked !!! Thank you very much !! My unrar program didn't work properly.

Answer (score 2):

SRT is a text file-format, containing subtitles. The complete name of `SRT` format is "Sub Rip".

The syntax is quite simple : 3 lines per subtitle.

- 1 : Number of the subtitle
- 2 : Duration
- 3 : The text

*Example :*

```
24
00:04:10,000 --> 00:04:11,600
You saved us.
```

=> *"You saved us." is the 24th subtitle and is displayed from 4m10s to 4m11s.*

---

You can **edit** .srt files with `gedit` or another text-editor like `mousepad`, `leafpad`.

You can **play** .srt files along with a video/movie with a media player like `vlc` or `totem`.

Note : For a more advanced use, like creating subtitles, translating or syncing them, you can use the application `gnome-subtitles` (available in the Software Centre). If you want to better the previsualisation in gnome-subtitles, you'll want to install `mplayer` along with it.

Answer (score 0):

There would be many ways to open a **.srt** file. Chose the best way you want if **right click** -> **open with** doesn't give you any option to open.

1. open terminal and pass the name of **srt** file as an argument to any text editor like **gedit**, **emacs**, **nano** or others. For example:

   ```
   gedit mysrtfile.srt
   ```

   or

   ```
   emacs mysrtfile.srt
   ```

   it will open your srt file in **gedit** or **emacs**
2. Open any text editor like **gedit** or **emacs** and **drag and drop** the **srt** file to it.

That's it. Hope it would help you. :)

Comment: Thank you, it actually opens gedit, but the file is empty, and it is not supposed to be .

Comment: @user253956: How is it possible? Have you tried any other text editor? Did you get subtitle when you import in media players?